Problems with Inventory Synchronization and Object State in Unity Network
Items Work Only for Host Player, Not for Client Player
In my multiplayer game, the item system works perfectly for the host player. However, I am encountering issues with the client player. Specifically:

Items that the client picks up do not display in their hand, but add into inventory.
The client cannot drop items.
The client is unable to see which items the host has dropped.

I have implemented the inventory system using Unity Netcode, but it seems that synchronization is not functioning correctly for the client. What could be causing these issues, and how can I ensure that item pickups and drops are properly synchronized between the host and client players? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
PlayerInventory script
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerInventory : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> allItems;
    public List<GameObject> collectedItems = new List<GameObject>();
    private int currentItemIndex = -1;
    private const int maxInventorySlots = 3;
    public Transform dropPosition;

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        foreach (GameObject item in allItems)
        {
            item.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    public void AddItemToInventoryServerRpc(string itemName, ulong networkObjectId, ServerRpcParams rpcParams = default)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Попытка добавить предмет {itemName} в инвентарь на сервере.");
        if (collectedItems.Count < maxInventorySlots)
        {
            GameObject itemToActivate = allItems.Find(item => item.name == itemName);
            if (itemToActivate != null)
            {
                collectedItems.Add(itemToActivate);
                HideItemForAllClientsClientRpc(itemName);
                ActivateItemClientRpc(collectedItems.Count - 1);
                SyncItemInHandClientRpc(itemName, true);
                RemoveItemFromWorldClientRpc(networkObjectId);
                Debug.Log($"Предмет {itemName} успешно добавлен в инвентарь.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Предмет {itemName} не найден среди скрытых предметов.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Инвентарь полон!");
        }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RemoveItemFromWorldClientRpc(ulong networkObjectId)
    {
        if (NetworkManager.Singleton.SpawnManager.SpawnedObjects.TryGetValue(networkObjectId, out NetworkObject networkObject))
        {
            GameObject itemObject = networkObject.gameObject;
            itemObject.SetActive(false);
            Destroy(itemObject);
        }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void HideItemForAllClientsClientRpc(string itemName)
    {
        GameObject itemToDeactivate = allItems.Find(item => item.name == itemName);
        if (itemToDeactivate != null)
        {
            itemToDeactivate.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void ActivateItemClientRpc(int index)
    {
        if (index >= 0 && index < collectedItems.Count)
        {
            if (currentItemIndex != -1)
            {
                collectedItems[currentItemIndex].SetActive(false);
            }
            currentItemIndex = index;
            collectedItems[currentItemIndex].SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log($"Активирован предмет: {collectedItems[currentItemIndex].name}");
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    public void DropCurrentItemServerRpc(ServerRpcParams rpcParams = default)
    {
        if (currentItemIndex >= 0 && currentItemIndex < collectedItems.Count)
        {
            GameObject currentItem = collectedItems[currentItemIndex];
            Debug.Log($"Выбрасывание предмета: {currentItem.name}");
            GameObject droppedItem = Instantiate(currentItem, dropPosition.position, Quaternion.identity);
            droppedItem.SetActive(true);

            var networkObject = droppedItem.GetComponent<NetworkObject>();
            if (networkObject != null && !networkObject.IsSpawned)
            {
                networkObject.Spawn(true);
            }

            Rigidbody rb = droppedItem.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (rb == null)
            {
                rb = droppedItem.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
                rb.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.Continuous;
                rb.mass = 1f;
            }

            rb.AddForce(dropPosition.forward * 1.5f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            currentItem.SetActive(false);
            collectedItems.RemoveAt(currentItemIndex);
            if (collectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                currentItemIndex = Mathf.Clamp(currentItemIndex - 1, 0, collectedItems.Count - 1);
                ActivateItemClientRpc(currentItemIndex);
            }
            else
            {
                currentItemIndex = -1;
                Debug.Log("Инвентарь пуст.");
            }

            SpawnDroppedItemClientRpc(droppedItem.name, droppedItem.transform.position, droppedItem.transform.rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Не удалось выбросить предмет: текущий индекс не валиден.");
        }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void SpawnDroppedItemClientRpc(string itemName, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        GameObject itemPrefab = allItems.Find(item => item.name == itemName);
        if (itemPrefab != null)
        {
            GameObject droppedItem = Instantiate(itemPrefab, position, rotation);
            droppedItem.SetActive(true);
            var networkObject = droppedItem.AddComponent<NetworkObject>();
            networkObject.Spawn(true);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner || collectedItems.Count == 0) return;

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") != 0f)
        {
            int direction = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0f ? 1 : -1;
            SwitchItem(direction);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {
            DropCurrentItemServerRpc();
        }
    }

    private void SwitchItem(int direction)
    {
        if (collectedItems.Count == 0) return;

        if (currentItemIndex != -1)
        {
            collectedItems[currentItemIndex].SetActive(false);
        }

        currentItemIndex += direction;
        if (currentItemIndex >= collectedItems.Count) currentItemIndex = 0;
        if (currentItemIndex < 0) currentItemIndex = collectedItems.Count - 1;

        ActivateItemClientRpc(currentItemIndex);
    }

    public bool HasItemInHand(string itemName)
    {
        return currentItemIndex != -1 && collectedItems[currentItemIndex].name == itemName;
    }

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    public void RemoveItemFromHandServerRpc(string itemName, ServerRpcParams rpcParams = default)
    {
        if (HasItemInHand(itemName))
        {
            Debug.Log($"Удаление предмета {itemName} из рук.");
            collectedItems[currentItemIndex].SetActive(false);
            collectedItems.RemoveAt(currentItemIndex);
            currentItemIndex = -1;
        }
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void SyncItemInHandClientRpc(string itemName, bool isActive)
    {
        GameObject itemInHand = collectedItems.Find(item => item.name == itemName);
        if (itemInHand != null)
        {
            itemInHand.SetActive(isActive);
        }
    }
}

PlayerInteract script
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerInteract : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public float interactionRange = 3f;
    public Camera playerCamera;
    public GameObject interactUI;
    private TMP_Text interactText;
    private Item itemInFocus;
    private PlayerInventory playerInventory;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (interactUI != null)
        {
            interactText = interactUI.GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
            if (interactText == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("TMP_Text компонент не найден на interactUI объекте!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("interactUI объект не присвоен в инспекторе!");
        }

        playerInventory = GetComponent<PlayerInventory>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (!IsOwner) return;

        Ray ray = playerCamera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2));
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, interactionRange))
        {
            Item item = hit.collider.GetComponent<Item>();
            if (item != null)
            {
                itemInFocus = item;
                ShowItemInfo(item);
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Нажата клавиша E для подбора предмета: " + item.itemName);
                    PickupItemServerRpc(item.NetworkObjectId);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                HideItemInfo();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            HideItemInfo();
        }
    }

    void ShowItemInfo(Item item)
    {
        if (interactText != null)
        {
            interactUI.SetActive(true);
            interactText.text = $"Нажмите E, чтобы подобрать {item.itemName}";
        }
    }

    void HideItemInfo()
    {
        if (interactUI != null)
        {
            interactUI.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    [ServerRpc]
    void PickupItemServerRpc(ulong itemId)
    {
        Debug.Log("ServerRpc вызван для предмета с ID: " + itemId);
        if (NetworkManager.Singleton.SpawnManager.SpawnedObjects.TryGetValue(itemId, out NetworkObject networkObject))
        {
            Item item = networkObject.GetComponent<Item>();
            if (item != null)
            {
                playerInventory.AddItemToInventoryServerRpc(item.itemName, itemId);
                Debug.Log("Предмет успешно добавлен в инвентарь и удален из мира.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Item не найден на объекте NetworkObject!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("NetworkObject с данным itemId не найден!");
        }
    }
}

Item script
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;

public class Item : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public string itemName;

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        if (IsServer)
        {
            //
        }

        
    }

    
}

I have spent a considerable amount of time trying to troubleshoot and resolve this issue but have not been able to find a solution. I have reviewed my code and network setup multiple times, but the problem persists.

I'm not sure about the Networking aspect, but SyncItemInHandClientRpc seems to do exactly what ActivateItemClientRpc is doing. Both are accessing the item you picked up from the world, which happens to be the last in collectedItems collection, and both are calling SetActive. Also there's RemoveItemFromHandServerRpc which is never called even though it's sensible to first check if there's sth else on hand before trying to put sth else in it. I don't see how you could have equipped the object with the code as is, at least through PickupItemServerRpc

In general currentItemIndex seems to only make sense for the instance that is owned by this player .. it will not have a correct value on the server side and the other way round ... I would debug through this and ensure you actually synchronize all required information...
